# Describe the set of harmonic functions $h(x,y)$on $\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $(x^2-y^2)h(x,y)$ is harmonic.

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is a qual-prep question:

Describe the set of harmonic functions $h(x,y)$on $\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $(x^2-y^2)h(x,y)$ is harmonic.

I've tried using the definition of harmonic function from which after some algebraic manipulations I can see that $h$ must satisfy $y \frac{\partial h}{\partial y} = x \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$. But I think the answer calls for a more explicit answer and I don't know how to go from here.

Comment: Damn!  Fat fingers, small 'droid, and once again I hit the ***POST*** button prematurely by accident.  Answer temporarily deleted, but stay tuned.  Sorry once again about any possible confusion.  Also, +1 for the question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $h$ satisfies your condition : $x h_x - yh_y = 0$ we can successively take partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ to get,

$xh_{xx} + h_x - yh_{xy} = 0 \quad \text{ and } \quad  xh_{yx} - h_y - yh_{yy}= 0 $.

Using the identities $h_{xx} + h_{yy} = 0$ and  $h_{xy} = h_{yx}$ we get from the above two equations,

$\quad h_x - xh_{yy} - y(\frac{1}{x}h_y + \frac{y}{x} h_{yy})=0;  \quad (x\not=0)$

$\implies -(x^2+ y^2) h_{yy} = 0  \implies h_{yy} = 0 $. Similarly we can arrive at $h_{xx} = 0$.

From $h_{yy} = 0$ you can write that $h(x,y) = A(x)y + B(x)$ and then compare with $h_{xx} = 0 $ to arrive at the conclusion that $B = constant $,  and $A(x) = Kx$ where $K$ is another constant. Thus all such harmonic functions are of the form $h(x,y) = Kxy + B$.

Comment: Cool and nice.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Very cool and nice indeed, sir! +1!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $h$ satisfies your condition, show that $h(x,y)$ is constant on branches of the hyperbolas $xy = c$.  Then what does $h(x,y) = f(xy)$ being harmonic tell you about $f$?

Comment: I don't understand your observation - how is h constant on the branches of the hyperbolas?

Comment: $\dfrac{d}{dx} h(x,c/x) = \ldots$